# passing the variable in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I am trying to pass the id of the person whosoever logs-in to my site. I am using Auth for login in cakephp. So can anyone tell me how to pass the value during the login and retrieve it at the home page? I am new to cakephp.

This is what I have tried.

app controller.php

```
class AppController extends Controller {
//...

public $components = array(
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
        'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'members', 'action' => 'home',$member['Member']['id']),
        'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'members', 'action' => 'index')
    )
);
```

MembersController.php

```
public function home($id = null) {
    $this->Member->id = $id;
}
```

home.ctp

```
<div align='center'><h2>Hi user welcome to home page </h2></div>
<?php
 //I am just trying to print the id of the logged in person
echo $this->Form->value('User.id');
?>
<?php
echo $this->Html->link('LogOut',array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'logout')); 
?>
```

Comment: The Cake community delivers a [great tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/blog.html) to get you started. Have a look at it and just start from the beginning. Don't skip anything, just do it all. Because there are a lot of conventions and very neat trick to get your first app running in no-time!

Comment: ok Jelmer thanks, what you said is true...

Answer (score 3):

```
echo $this->Form->value('User.id');
```

Is part of the [FormHelper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html).

If you would like to have your form prefilled, make use of the conventions. Simply create an input field like this:

```
echo $this->Form->input('User.id');
```

If the `$this->request->data` contains this value (`$this->request->data['User']['id']`) it will automatically fill your form.

In order to retrieve values from the [AuthComponent](http://api20.cakephp.org/class/auth-component) You can simply do something like `$userName= $this->Auth->user('name');` (Just make sure the column 'name' exists in your 'users` database).

In order to pass variables to your view, you can simply use the method [set](http://api20.cakephp.org/class/controller#method-Controllerset) which is defined in the `Controller`, which is extended by the `AppController` which is extend by `FooBarsController`.

If you want to set this variable to your view (as mentioned earlier) use `set`.

```
$this->set('userName', $userName);
```

In your view you can now do:

```
printf('Welcome %s', $userName);
```

- [Blog tutorial to get your started](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/blog.html)
- [AuthComponent](http://api20.cakephp.org/class/auth-component)
- [FormHelper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html)
- [How Views work](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html)
- [How Controllers work](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html)
- [How Models work](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models.html)